# navigating to another view if count=1 in php file using sench

Tags: php, ajax, sencha-touch-2

i created a sencha touch application,in my controller i used the ajax code as

```
   if (condition is true){
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: 'http://localhost/../abc.php?action=check',
                                params: valuesUser,
                                method: 'POST',

                                success: function(response){
                                    var text = response.responseText;
                                    console.log(response.responseText);
                                     if(response.responseText == 'exists')
                                {
                                //Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text);
                                Ext.getCmp('loginform').destroy();
                                Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('RegisterForm.view.Main'));
                                }
                                else{
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success',text);
                                }
}

                                failure : function(response) {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Error','Error while submitting the form');
                                    console.log(response.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                           }
                        else{
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'All the fields are necessary');
                        }
```

my abc.php contains the following code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('RegisterForm',$con);
if($_REQUEST["action"]== "check"){
$query = "SELECT name FROM userdetails WHERE name ='" . $_POST['userName'] . "' ";
      $queryresult = mysql_query($query);
      $count = mysql_num_rows($queryresult);
      if($count == 1)
        {
            echo('values are in the db');
        }
       else
        {
            echo("values aren't in the db");
        }
}
?
```

if contion is true in the controller code it goes to abc.php and checks name exists in the db are or n't.if name exist then it should open another view ,otherwise it should display alert msg as values aren't in the db.but by using the above code ,im navigating to another view in both cases (values are in db,values aren't in the db).can anyone help me to do this. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put condition in your sencha code based on the returned value from PHP. Something like:

```
if(response.responseText == 'exists')
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('RegisterForm.view.Main'));
else
    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', text);
```

Moreover do

```
echo 'exists';
```

instead of

```
echo('values are in the db');
```

Comment: i updated the code as u said,but no change still im navigating to another view ,if values aren't in the db

Comment: Make sure that, value is being posted to the PHP script.

Comment: make sure you updated echo('values are in the db'); to echo "exists"; in abc.php
What text you see in console which is being written by
    console.log(response.responseText);

Comment: yes,im sure.and now im getting the alert msg as exists (if exists),otherwise shows alert msg as values aren't in the db.but when alert msg as exists ,it should navigate to main view.but it doesn't navigate to another view

Comment: in console im getting 'exists' text if values are in the db,but it doesn't navigate to main view